# Required / included once. Already defined notices

Tags: php

Not sure why this is happening.

```
Notice: Constant HOST already defined in con.php on line 11

Notice: Constant USER already defined in con.php on line 12

Notice: yardy yardy lalala etc
```

All the calls I make to con.php use require_once or include_once.

con.php consists of :

```
define("HOST", "x");
     define("USER", "x");
     define("PASSWORD", "x");
     define("DATABASE", "x");
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: does the file retuning the above error have them defined too maybe? Or another include file also have them in? Or another include file also includes con.php in it?

Comment: most php error messages are actully quite helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it all. Those constants are defined elsewhere. One way to work around that is to check to see if they are defined and then only define them if they are not.

```
defined("HOST")            || define("HOST", "x");
defined("USER")            || define("USER", "x");
defined("PASSWORD")        || define("PASSWORD", "x");
defined(define("DATABASE") || define("DATABASE", "x");
```

The *better* solution would be to try to avoid including the files they are defined in more then once. But if you can't help it then the above method should solve your problem.